# Constructor and Destructor of initialized static thread_local struct not invoked

Tags: c++

The code below supposedly initializes a `static thread-local` and `static` struct.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Tracer {
public:
  Tracer(const char *new_name) : name{new_name} {
    printf("%s : Constructor()\n", this->name);
  }

  ~Tracer() {
    printf("%s : Destructor()\n", this->name);
  }

private:
  const char *name;
};

// 1. Thread-Local Storage Duration
static thread_local Tracer t_thread_local{"Thread-Local Storage Duration"};

// 2. Static Storage Duration
static Tracer t_static{"Static Storage Duration"};

int main() {
  printf("Start Program\n");
}
```

However, I don't see the message expected from the `static thread-local` struct Constructor/Destructor. The output printed only shows messages from the `static` struct. Am I missing something?

```
Static Storage Duration : Constructor()
Start Program
Static Storage Duration : Destructor()
```

Comment: I've seen this question on SO before. The point is that your thread is not using `t_thread_local` and therefore won't even bother constructing it. Imagine you have a big program with a lot of thread_locals but only use a small portion of them, it would be very inefficient to construct/initialize all thread_locals (including the not used once) on every new thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption that merely declaring & defining these objects must assuredly trigger pre-`main` construction is incorrect.

> [`[basic.stc.thread/2]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.thread#2): *[ Note:* A variable with thread storage duration is initialized as specified in [basic.start.static], [basic.start.dynamic], and [stmt.dcl] and, if constructed, is destroyed on thread exit ([basic.start.term]). *— end note ]*
>
> [`[basic.start.dynamic/5]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#5): It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized. *[..]*

There are in fact a number of similar rules in `basic.start.dynamic`.

Point is, your program doesn't do very much, and it certainly doesn't use `t_thread_local`, so it's up to the compiler as to whether `t_thread_local` will ever really exist and, if so, when.